# Нужно переместить элементы при ресайзе в другой блок

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть пункты меню с фильтрами. 
Вот верстка

```
<div class="items_sect clearfix">
    <div class="left filters">
        <div class="item_wrapp">
            <p>Фильтр 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item_wrapp">
            <p>Фильтр 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item_wrapp">
            <p>Фильтр 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item_wrapp">
            <p>Фильтр 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item_wrapp">
            <p>Фильтр 5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item_wrapp">
            <p>Фильтр 6</p>
        </div>                              
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="resp_coord"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fiter_resp"></div>
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы при сужении окна, блоки item_wrapp не переходили на вторую строку. То есть нужно чтобы они переходили в блок filter_resp. А при увеличении ширины ставились обратно на свободное место в том же порядке. Вот как на пример на этом сайте  [Пример работы адаптивности меню фильтров при ресайзе](https://ru.airbnb.com/s/plus_homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fselect_homes&click_referer=t%3ASEE_ALL%7Csid%3Ad1f17346-c3cb-4700-a38b-d947711ce8bb%7Cst%3AHOME_GROUPING_SELECT_HOMES&superhost=false&guests=0&adults=0&children=0&title_type=SELECT_GROUPING&search_type=FILTER_CHANGE&allow_override%5B%5D=&price_max=29976&price_min=2016&s_tag=JtWdrD79)

Как это сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно дополнительно создать HTML разметку внутри `.filter-resp` и начинать показывать её (задаёте `display: block`) с определённой ширины экрана. В то же время вы скрываете `.filters` начиная с этой ширины.

Comment: Спасибо за совет - подумаю